# modificar el name de un input con jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Alguien me puede ayudar, estoy creando elementos dinamicamente espscificamente inputs con el metodo .clone() con jquery
pero quero cambiar el name de los input que clono,
por ejemplo si tengo el siguiente input

Este es el input que clono

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="inputTemplate" name="inputTemplate">
```

Despues de clonarlo le quiero cambiar el name, por ejemplo a:

```
 <input class="form-control" type="text" id="inputclonado" name="inputclonado">
```

Comment: Deberias de incluir el codigo jQuery donde clonas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es cuestion de utilizar el metodo `.attr(...)`: [JQuery attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

Ejemplo (adicionalmente recomendaria que cambies el id luego de clonarlo):

```
var elementoClonado = $("#" + id).clone()
elementoClonado.attr('id', 'nuevo id');
elementoClonado.attr('name', 'nuevo nombre');
```

Comment: gracias amigo si me sirvio, de casualidad sabes como validar todos esos campos dinamicos con bootstrap Validator?

Comment: Hola @Alejandro.C si la respuesta sirvió para la solución te invito a que consideres marcarla como aceptada, eso será de ayuda a próximos desarrolladores que posiblemente puedan tener tu mismo problema; en cuanto a el tema de la validación debes hacer una nueva pregunta, saludos.

Comment: @Bender  como la marco? si eres tan amable de decirme, si es con la fecha hacia arriba ya le di un punto

Comment: @Alejandro.C para marcar una respuesta como aceptada debes darle click al chulo gris que está justo debajo de las flechas, al darle clic el chulo cambiará su color a verde y así sabrás que la respuesta fue marcada correctamente, te invito a que te hagas el [tour] si no lo has hecho para que entiendas bien el funcionamiento del sitio, de hecho revisando en tu historial de preguntas veo que en algunas encontraste solución y nunca marcaste las respuesta aceptadas lo cual es importante hacerlo.